# Foundation Reveal issue if I have multiple links that opens the same modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, focus, zurb-foundation

I have a page with multiple links that opens a foundation reveal modal. Each link opens the same modal. The problem is that I have some links on the top of the page, and some links on the bottom, so when I click on some link from the top, if I close the modal, the last link get the focus, so the page scrolls down to the last element that opens this unique modal.

Someone knows how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/10604 . One workaround is to open the modal via js instead of with data-open on each link. ie:

```
$('.open-my-modal-link').click(function() {
  $('#my-modal').foundation('open'); 
  ...
```